# Connecting Teiid with Elastic Search

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, wildfly, teiid

I am trying to connect Teiid with Elastic Search. I downloaded wildfly and teiid.jboss.org/downloads/.I don't know what to do next .The documentation is confusing please help me.

Comment: What would be use case using Elastic Search with Teiid? So far we have not provided any direct integration points with ES. There is integration with SOLR, possibly as an index cache.

Comment: So recommended way how to do fulltext search over VDB (possibly consist from multiple db sources) is to integrate SOLR? Any other possibilities?

Thanks.